# How to see SSIS packages on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My issue pertains specifically to SSIS packages saved to "SQL Server" through the Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. When a package is saved to "SQL Server" instead of "File System", it does not save to the Integration Services Catalog. My question is, how do you access those packages for editing or viewing.

I.E., I want to make a minor adjustment to an SSIS package stored in SQL Server, but I do not recall all the changes and options I made when initially setting it up (so I cannot simply recreate it). Additionally, I'd like to delete old test versions of the package.

Comment: Hi Matt, I think there was some confusion with the language in your question. I thought you were asking about saving using the `File System` option instead of the `SQL Server` option. I understand now that you are asking the about the `SQL Server` option, and have updated the question. I will look into this further and get back to you.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 14.0.

Comment: I added a new answer that I think covers all the questions you had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Wizard documentation:

The wizard saves the package in the msdb database in the sysssispackages table. This option does not save the package to the SSIS Catalog database (SSISDB).

Removing records from this table will remove the package.

You can open the package to edit it with SQL Server Data Tools. Create a new SSIS project, and then in the Solution Explorer pane, right-click on the SSIS Packages folder icon and choose `Add existing package...`.

In the next dialog, you'd choose "SQL Server" as the package location, put in your server address and login credentials, and then for "Package Path" click on the three dots and it will let you browse to the package. Hit "OK" and your package will then be loaded into SSDT.